# How do I read only the last line of a csv file in Java?

Tags: java, csv, bufferedreader

I have a csv file that doesn't always have the same number of lines. However, I want a method to only read me the last line, so I can access the first column of that last line. So far I haven't found a solution, that does exactly that.

Right now I'm just at the point were I would read every single line with BufferedReader and save it into an Array.

```java
public void readPreviousEntryID(){
    String path = "csvs/cartEntries.csv";
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader((new FileReader(path)));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine() != null)) {
            String[] values = line.split(",");
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Normally I would then access the first entry of every line by using values[0]. But I just want the first value of the last line.

I thought about counting the number of lines in the while loop by incrementing an integer and then using the final value of that integer to access the corresponding line, but I'm not sure if this would work or how I would implement that.

I hope I included enough information to make the problem understandable. This is my first question here and I'm quite new to Java.

Comment: Just read until the last non-null (and non-empty) line

Comment: @MarkRotteveel So just make the while loop stop before it hits null? line = br.readLine() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply read the lines of the file in a loop and save the `values` of the last line read. After the loop terminates, `values` contains the contents of the last line in the file.

```java
public void readPreviousEntryID() throws IOException {
    String path = "csvs/cartEntries.csv";
    try (FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)) {
        String[] values = null;
        String line = br.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            values = line.split(",");
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        if (values == null) {
            throw new IOException("File is empty.");
        }
        // Handle 'values[0]'
    }
}
```

The advantage of the above code is that you don't need to store the entire file contents in the computer memory. If the CSV file is very large, you may get [OutOfMemoryError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks002.html).

Note that is important to close a file after you have finished reading it. Since Java 7 you can use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Rather than catch the `IOException` and wrap it in a `RuntimeException`, I suggest that you simply declare that method `readPreviousEntryID` may throw an `IOException`. Refer to [Unchecked Exceptions — The Controversy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html).

It is probably also a good idea to check, after the loop terminates, that `values` contains the expected number of elements, e.g.

```java
if (values.length == 5) {
    // Handle 'values[0]'
}
else {
    throw new IOException("Invalid last line.");
}
```

### Edit

Alternatively, no need to split every line. Just save the last line read and split that last line after the loop terminates.

```java
public void readPreviousEntryID() throws IOException {
    String path = "csvs/cartEntries.csv";
    try (FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)) {
        String lastLine = null;
        String line = br.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            lastLine = line;
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        if (lastLine == null) {
            throw new IOException("File is empty.");
        }
        String[] values = lastLine.split(",");
        // Handle 'values[0]'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, this looks quite elegant!

Answer (score 0):

Why not stored all lines into List and get last line details such as follows

```
private List<String[]> readLines = new ArrayList<>();
    
public void readPreviousEntryID(){
    String path = "csvs/cartEntries.csv";
    try {
        String line;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] values = line.split(",");
            readLines.add(values);
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String[] getLastLine() {
    return readLines.get(readLines.size()-1);
}
```

This above function will gives the last row of csv file.

Comment: Ok, seems if you don't want to used List collection, here is alternate solution 
`lastLine = null; 
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] values = line.split(",");
    readLines.add(values);
    lastLine = line;
}
if(lastLine != null) {
 System.out.println(lastLine);
}

Answer (score 0):

In Linux one would use the `tail` command to print the *n* last lines. Search `java tail` will get you some implementations.

A good fast implementation for large files would use a RandomAccessFile, maybe a MemoryMappedByteBuffer, and search back from the end for a `\n`.

In your case you can keep it simple.

```
public String readPreviousEntryID(){
    Path path = Paths.get("csvs/cartEntries.csv");
    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path, Charset.defaultCharset())) {
        return lines
                   .filter(line -> !line.isEmpty())
                   .reduce("", (acc, line) -> line);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // You gave a relative path, show the actual full path:
        System.out.println("File not found: " + Files.toAbsolutePath());
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } // Automatically closes the Stream lines, even on exception or return.
}
```

- **Try-with-resources** `try (... declarations of AutoCloseables ...) { ... }` ensuring the call to `.close()`.
- **Stream**, the newest walk through items. Here skipping empty lines and "accumulating" just the last line. You need not keep all lines in memory.
- **Lambdas**, `x -> ...` or `(x, y) -> ...` declare an anonymous function with 1 resp. 2 parameter declarations.
- **Path** is a generalisation of disk file only `File`. Path can also be from an URL, inside a zip file etcetera.
- **Files** is a worthwile utility class providing many `Path` related goodies. [`Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html).

Answer (score 0):

Some good Answers have been posted. Here is a variation using streams.

Also, learn about [NIO.2](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_I/O_(Java)#JDK_7_and_NIO.2) as the modern way to work with files in Java.

Some untested code to try:

```
Path path = Paths.get( "/csvs" , "cartEntries.csv" ) ;
Optional < String > lastLine = 
    Files
        .lines( path )
        .reduce( ( previousLine , currentLine ) -> currentLine ) ;
if( lastLine.isPresent() ) {
    String[] parts = lastLine.get().split( "," ) ;
    …
}
```

Or, re-organized into a one-liner:

```
String[] parts =
    Files
        .lines( 
            Paths.get( "/csvs" , "cartEntries.csv" )
        )
        .reduce( 
            ( previousLine , currentLine ) -> currentLine 
        ) 
        .map(
            line -> line.split.( "," )
        )
        .orElse(
            String[] :: new
        )
;
```